# Parallax Effect on Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax, parallax.js

A perfect example of what I am looking to achieve is on this page as soon as you land on it (parallax BG, text fades, and text is parallaxed):[themenectar.com](http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-business/)

I am using parallax.js for my backgrounds which works great. I am also using this snippet below which fades my title out on scroll:

```
function scrollBanner() {
    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('.page-title, .breadcrumbs').css({
            'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/200),
        });
    });
}

scrollBanner();
```

Everything works fine, except for that I am stumped on how to achieve a parallax effect on my title.

Right now when I scroll my title just scrolls up, as it would any other element. How could I go about making my text parallax too? Such as in the example on [themenectar.com](http://themenectar.com/demo/salient-business/)

Comment: Do you have a working demo of your own code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use your scrollPos variable to manipulate the CSS property `transform: translateY(n);` something like this:

```
var transY = scrollPos / 2;
$('.page-title').css({'transform':`translateY(${transY}px)`});
```

Of course play around with the numbers to get the desired effect.

The Transform CSS property is good for performance reasons (https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

Comment: Oh wow, that worked, thanks so much. I really must make myself more familiar with JS. Cheers!